# Eclipse Kepler crashes when opening an ext-js javascript file

Tags: javascript, eclipse-kepler

Eclipse-kepler keeps crashing when I try to open a JavaScript file.

Error:

> Exception in thread
>   "org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler"
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded    at
>   org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.isErrorState(Parser.java:5558)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:5688)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:6045)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:5997)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:4602)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.accept(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:166)

The code has some menu items and few JavaScript functions which works on the menu items. I'm working on a Mac

Comment: What does your javascript file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting an out of memory error you might try upping your max memory by adjusting the '-Xmx' parameter in your eclipse.ini file to 1024.